# IDE compiles incorrect file after renaming them

Tags: arduino-ide

I am using the stand alone Arduino IDE to build some projects, and I have a few `.cpp` files now, but during work I renamed them `.c` and back. When compiling the project now (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>), it is still trying to compile the `.c` files. But, I don't even see them on disk!

Changing the `.cpp` makes no difference. I am used to IDEs having some kind of project file, or a "clean project" option, but I cannot find those here.

Comment: are the files open in tabs in IDE? IDE takes source code from the editors. a 'sketch' is a folder with source files. all are compiled

Comment: The Arduino IDE copies all files to a `tmp` folder. Try restarting the IDE.

Comment: A restart did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Arduino IDE does not monitor changes to open files. So if you rename or change a file externally (i.e. in another editor), the IDE won't update the file contents. Therefore, after such a change, a restart might be necessary.

Note: If you use another editor to change a file but only compile (and upload) in the IDE, this will work, because the compiler correctly reads the updated file. But editing the source in the IDE and an external editor at the same time might overwrite either change!